# I just can not understand DR 712

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, c++17, one-definition-rule

[DR 712](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#712) was responsible for the change in the wording of [basic.def.odr]/2 in C++11 to the current wording today, in [[basic.def.odr]2 and 3](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#2). But I'm still trying to understand the reason for the change, as stated in the DR, as follows:

> **712. Are integer constant operands of a conditional-expression “used?”**
>
> In describing static data members initialized inside the class
>   definition, 9.2.3.2 [class.static.data] paragraph 3 says,
>
> The member shall still be defined in a namespace scope if it is used
>   in the program...
>
> The definition of “used” is in 3.2 [basic.def.odr] paragraph 1:
>
> An object or non-overloaded function whose
>   name appears as a potentially-evaluated
>       expression is used unless it is an object that satisfies the requirements for appearing in a 
>       constant expression (5.20 [expr.const]) and the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1 [conv.lval])
>       is immediately applied.
>
> Now consider the following example:
>
> ```
>  struct S {
>       static const int a = 1;
>       static const int b = 2;
>  };
>  int f(bool x) {
>       return x ? S::a : S::b;
>  }
> ```
>
> According to the current wording of the Standard, this example
>   requires that `S::a` and `S::b` be defined in a namespace scope. The
>   reason for this is that, according to 5.16 [expr.cond] paragraph 4,
>   the result of this conditional-expression is an lvalue and the
>   lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is applied to that, not directly to the
>   object, **so this fails the “immediately applied” requirement**. This is
>   surprising and unfortunate, since only the values and not the
>   addresses of the static data members are used. (This problem also
>   applies to the proposed resolution of issue 696.)

Well, if the "immediately applied requirement fails, then the expressions `S::a` and `S::b` in the conditional expression are **not** used (odr-used), and so, the respective static members of `struct S` will **not** need to be defined in namespace scope. But this is exactly the opposite of what the DR is saying. What am I missing???

Comment: The original wording said that something is odr-used *unless* ... l2r is immediately applied, and since `S::a` and `S::b` were not immediately subjected to l2r (only the conditional expression was), they *were* odr-used, since the "unless" part did not apply.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're missing the point of the `used` definition:

```
it is used UNLESS ( (const) AND (immediately applied) )
```

So, if "immediately applied" is false, then the UNLESS is false, and thus it is used.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The two conditions have to be satisfied for the object not to be used.

Answer (score 2):

> An object or non-overloaded function whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression is used unless[...]

Well, `S::a` and `S::b` appear in a potentially-evaluated expression within `f`.

So they are used, unless either of the following exceptions apply.

> [...] it is an object that satisfies the requirements for appearing in a     constant expression (5.20 [expr.const]) and the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1 [conv.lval]) is immediately applied.

Well, it is an object that satisfied the requirement for appearing in a constant expression.  So it passes that test.

But the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is not immediately applied.

So it fails that test.

As this entire section is under "unless", the failure means that the previous case applies; the object is considered "used".