# How can a pure-virtual function be invoked without its name being explicitly qualified?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, virtual-functions, one-definition-rule

You'll find the following text in `[basic.def.odr]/2` in C++11:

> A virtual member function is odr-used if it is not pure. **A
>   non-overloaded function whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated
>   expression** or a member of a set of candidate functions, if selected by
>   overload resolution when referred to from a potentially-evaluated
>   expression, **is odr-used, unless it is a pure virtual function and its
>   name is not explicitly qualified**.

According to highlighted text above, it's possible to invoke a pure virtual function as a potentially-evaluated expression, without its name being explicitly qualified. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2089176/1042389) by [Michael Burr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12711/michael-burr) seems to show the only way, one can call a pure virtual function, and it has to use a qualified name.

PS: For those wondering why am I still referring the question to the C++11 Standard, please see my prior question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42534495/4463557).

Comment: As a guess, `struct Foo { virtual void bar() = 0; }; Foo* f = blah;  f->bar();`; `bar` is a named pure virtual function (selected for overload resolution) and its name is not explicitly qualified.  Uncertain, so just a comment.

Comment: What Yakk said. Note the difference between a function being selected by overload resolution and the function actually being called.  (Though pure virtual functions can actually be called, during constructors or destructors; this is undefined behavior.)

Comment: @aschepler, They can also be called normally, with qualification, like the answer linked by the OP shows. Your comment suggests to me that calling a pure virtual function requires a more obscure case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can a pure-virtual function be invoked without its name being explicitly qualified?

That's the ordinary case. To borrow Yakk's example from the comments:

```
struct Foo {
    virtual void bar() = 0;
};

void quux(Foo* f) {
    f->bar();
}
```

Here the pure virtual function `Foo::bar` is being invoked without explicit qualification. Therefore, according to the quoted paragraph, `Foo::bar` is **not** odr-used, and therefore it doesn't need to be defined. Instead, its non-pure overriders in derived classes are odr-used, and they are the functions that need to be defined.

But if you explicitly qualify a call to a pure virtual function, then you cause it to become odr-used, and it requires a definition. This most commonly happens with pure virtual destructors, because a derived class destructor always invokes base class destructors *as though they were fully qualified*. That's why pure virtual destructors need to be defined.

Comment: You example above doesn't make any sense to me. What is `blah`?

Comment: @JoãoAfonso Some expression of type `Foo*`. It doesn't matter what it is.

Comment: @Brian `Here the pure virtual function Foo::bar is being invoked without explicit qualification.` This is wrong. `f->bar();` **doesn't invoke** the pure virtual function `Foo::bar()`, but some virtual function `D::bar()`, where `D` is a concrete class derived from `Foo`, and `f` is the address of some object of class `D`, materialized in the expression `blah`.

Comment: @JoãoAfonso If that bothers you, file an editorial issue against the standard. I explained to you what the paragraph means. If you don't believe me, I hope someone else writes an answer that you will believe.

Comment: @Brian I'm accepting your answer, but I think [this post](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/msg/std-discussion/dgdLFuXpjkU/28s9kkgqAQAJ) by Nicol Bolas in C++ std-discussion provided me with [the insight](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/msg/std-discussion/dgdLFuXpjkU/xSA5-OJJAQAJ) that I was looking for in my question.